# FATAL exception Thread -12

Tags: java, android

App is crashing just after the timer finishes its time... I just have to move to activity lvl_2 after the timeout .

Its a game with 5 levels namely Game,lvl2_game,lvl3_game,lvl4_game,lvl5_game
with 8 layout lvl_1,lvl_2,lvl_3,lvl_4,lvl_5 ,menu , home,score
I have to move from Game.java to lvl2_game after the timeout
But its returning `FATAl exception : Thread -12 
Java.lang.IlligalStateException`

```
public class Game extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    MediaPlayer coinSong;
    float fx1,fx2,fx3,fx4,fy1,fy2,fy3,fy4;
    float xb1,xb2,xb3,xb4,yb1,yb2,yb3,yb4;
    int result=0;
    float xc1_1,xc1_2,xc1_3,xc1_4,yc1_1,yc1_2,yc1_3,yc1_4;
    int chk=1,delay,chkc1=0,chkc2=0,chkc3=0,chkc4=0,chkc5=0,chkc6=0,chkc7=0,chkc8=0,chkc9=0,chkc10=0,chkc11=0,chkc12=0;
    float xc2_1,xc2_2,xc2_3,xc2_4,yc2_1,yc2_2,yc2_3,yc2_4;
    float xc3_1,xc3_2,xc3_3,xc3_4,yc3_1,yc3_2,yc3_3,yc3_4;
    float xc4_1,xc4_2,xc4_3,xc4_4,yc4_1,yc4_2,yc4_3,yc4_4;
    float xc5_1,xc5_2,xc5_3,xc5_4,yc5_1,yc5_2,yc5_3,yc5_4;
    float xc6_1,xc6_2,xc6_3,xc6_4,yc6_1,yc6_2,yc6_3,yc6_4;
    float xc7_1,xc7_2,xc7_3,xc7_4,yc7_1,yc7_2,yc7_3,yc7_4;
    float xc8_1,xc8_2,xc8_3,xc8_4,yc8_1,yc8_2,yc8_3,yc8_4;
    float xc9_1,xc9_2,xc9_3,xc9_4,yc9_1,yc9_2,yc9_3,yc9_4;
    float xc10_1,xc10_2,xc10_3,xc10_4,yc10_1,yc10_2,yc10_3,yc10_4;
    float xc11_1,xc11_2,xc11_3,xc11_4,yc11_1,yc11_2,yc11_3,yc11_4;
    float xc12_1,xc12_2,xc12_3,xc12_4,yc12_1,yc12_2,yc12_3,yc12_4;

    float xe1,xe2,xe3,xe4,xe11,xe22,xe33,xe44,ye1,ye2,ye3,ye4,ye11,ye22,ye33,ye44;

    float   sensorX,
            sencurrX,
            x,
            y,
            eatX=0,
            eatY,
            ballX,
            ballY,
            sencurrY,
            sensorY;

    float   eatX2=eatX,
            eatY2=eatY+100;


    int score;

    Bitmap  ball,
            finish,
            eat,
            eat1,
            eat2,
            eat3,
            eat4,
            coin,
            coin1,
            coin2,
            coin3,
            coin4,
            coin5,
            coin6,
            coin7,
            coin8,
            coin9,
            coin10,
            coin11,
            wallp;
    SensorManager sm;
    WakeLock wL;
    MySurface game_surface ; 
    public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        SurfaceHolder my_holder;
        Thread game_thread= null;
        boolean isRunning= false;
        public MySurface(Context context){
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context);
            my_holder = getHolder();

        }
        public void pause(){
            isRunning =false;
            while(true){
                try {
                    game_thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            game_thread= null;
        }
        public void resume(){
            isRunning=true;
            game_thread = new Thread(this);
            game_thread.start();
            wL.acquire();
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(isRunning){
                if(!my_holder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;
                Canvas canvas= my_holder.lockCanvas();
                //delay++;

                canvas.drawRGB(175,225,251);
                //canvas.drawBitmap(wallp,0, 0, null);
                float centerX=(canvas.getWidth()/2)-(ball.getWidth()/2);
                float centerY=(canvas.getHeight()/2)-(ball.getHeight()/2);

                canvas.drawBitmap(finish,0,350, null);


                // Coin Layer 1

                if(chkc1==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin,50,50,null);
                if(chkc2==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin1,50+coin.getWidth(),50,null);
                if(chkc3==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin2,50+coin.getWidth()*2,50,null);
                if(chkc4==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin3,50+coin.getWidth()*3,50,null);


                // Coin Layer 2


                if(chkc5==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin4,100,150,null);
                if(chkc6==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin5,100+coin.getWidth(),150,null);
                if(chkc7==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin6,100+coin.getWidth()*2,150,null);
                if(chkc8==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin7,100+coin.getWidth()*3,150,null);



                // Coin Layer 3


                if(chkc9==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin8,50,250,null);
                if(chkc10==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin9,50+coin.getWidth(),250,null);
                if(chkc11==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin10,50+coin.getWidth()*2,250,null);
                if(chkc12==0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(coin11,50+coin.getWidth()*3,250,null);

                // Two eat 
                canvas.drawBitmap(eat1, eatX,eatY, null);
                float eatt;
                eatt=(canvas.getHeight()- finish.getHeight())- eat.getHeight()-eatY2;
                canvas.drawBitmap(eat, eatX2,eatt , null);

                ballX=(centerX+sensorX*20);
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                ballX=Float.valueOf(df.format(ballX));
                DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                ballY=(centerY+sensorY*50);
                ballY=Float.valueOf(df2.format(ballY));

        // Coordinates of  Coins
                xc1_1=50;
                xc1_2=50+coin.getWidth();
                xc1_3=50+coin.getWidth();
                xc1_4=50;
                yc1_1=50;
                yc1_2=50;
                yc1_3=50-coin.getHeight();
                yc1_4=50-coin.getHeight();

                xc2_1=50+coin.getWidth();
                xc2_2=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc2_3=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc2_4=50+coin.getWidth();
                yc2_1=50;
                yc2_2=50;
                yc2_3=50-coin.getHeight();
                yc2_4=50-coin.getHeight();

                xc3_1=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc3_2=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc3_3=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc3_4=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                yc3_1=50;
                yc3_2=50;
                yc3_3=50-coin.getHeight();
                yc3_4=50-coin.getHeight();

                xc4_1=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc4_2=50+coin.getWidth()*4;
                xc4_3=50+coin.getWidth()*4;
                xc4_4=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                yc4_1=50;
                yc4_2=50;
                yc4_3=50-coin.getHeight();
                yc4_4=50-coin.getHeight();

                xc5_1=100;
                xc5_2=100+coin.getWidth();
                xc5_3=100+coin.getWidth();
                xc5_4=100;
                yc5_1=150;
                yc5_2=150;
                yc5_3=150-coin.getHeight();
                yc5_4=150-coin.getWidth();

                xc6_1=100+coin.getWidth();
                xc6_2=100+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc6_3=100+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc6_4=100+coin.getWidth();
                yc6_1=150;
                yc6_2=150;
                yc6_3=150-coin.getHeight();
                yc6_4=150-coin.getHeight();

                xc7_1=100+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc7_2=100+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc7_3=100+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc7_4=100+coin.getWidth()*2;
                yc7_1=150;
                yc7_2=150;
                yc7_3=150-coin.getHeight();
                yc7_4=150-coin.getHeight();

                xc8_1=100+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc8_2=100+coin.getWidth()*4;
                xc8_3=100+coin.getWidth()*4;
                xc8_4=100+coin.getWidth()*3;
                yc8_1=150;
                yc8_2=150;
                yc8_3=150-coin.getHeight();
                yc8_4=150-coin.getHeight();

                xc9_1=50;
                xc9_2=50+coin.getWidth();
                xc9_3=50+coin.getWidth();
                xc9_4=50;
                yc9_1=250;
                yc9_2=250;
                yc9_3=250-coin.getHeight();
                yc9_4=250-coin.getHeight();

                xc10_1=50+coin.getWidth();
                xc10_2=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc10_3=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc10_4=50+coin.getWidth();
                yc10_1=250;
                yc10_2=250;
                yc10_3=250-coin.getHeight();
                yc10_4=250-coin.getWidth();

                xc11_1=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                xc11_2=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc11_3=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc11_4=50+coin.getWidth()*2;
                yc11_1=250;
                yc11_2=250;
                yc11_3=250-coin.getHeight();
                yc11_4=250-coin.getWidth();

                xc12_1=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                xc12_2=50+coin.getWidth()*4;
                xc12_3=50+coin.getWidth()*4;
                xc12_4=50+coin.getWidth()*3;
                yc12_1=250;
                yc12_2=250;
                yc12_3=250-coin.getHeight();
                yc12_4=250-coin.getWidth();

        // Ball Touching Coin           

                if(     ((xb1>xc1_4)&&(xb1<xc1_2))&&((yb1>yc1_4)&&(yb1<yc1_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc1_4)&&(xb2<xc1_2))&&((yb2>yc1_4)&&(yb2<yc1_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc1_4)&&(xb3<xc1_2))&&((yb3>yc1_4)&&(yb3<yc1_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc1_4)&&(xb4<xc1_2))&&((yb4>yc1_4)&&(yb4<yc1_2))      )
                {
                    chkc1=1;
                    result+=5;
                    coinSong.start();
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc2_4)&&(xb1<xc2_2))&&((yb1>yc2_4)&&(yb1<yc2_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc2_4)&&(xb2<xc2_2))&&((yb2>yc2_4)&&(yb2<yc2_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc2_4)&&(xb3<xc2_2))&&((yb3>yc2_4)&&(yb3<yc2_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc2_4)&&(xb4<xc2_2))&&((yb4>yc2_4)&&(yb4<yc2_2))      )
                {
                    chkc2=1;
                    coinSong.start();
                    result+=5;
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc3_4)&&(xb1<xc3_2))&&((yb1>yc3_4)&&(yb1<yc3_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc3_4)&&(xb2<xc3_2))&&((yb2>yc3_4)&&(yb2<yc3_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc3_4)&&(xb3<xc3_2))&&((yb3>yc3_4)&&(yb3<yc3_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc3_4)&&(xb4<xc3_2))&&((yb4>yc3_4)&&(yb4<yc3_2))      )
                {
                    chkc3=1;
                    result+=5;
                    coinSong.start();
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc4_4)&&(xb1<xc4_2))&&((yb1>yc4_4)&&(yb1<yc4_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc4_4)&&(xb2<xc4_2))&&((yb2>yc4_4)&&(yb2<yc4_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc4_4)&&(xb3<xc4_2))&&((yb3>yc4_4)&&(yb3<yc4_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc4_4)&&(xb4<xc4_2))&&((yb4>yc4_4)&&(yb4<yc4_2))      )
                {
                    chkc4=1;
                    coinSong.start();
                    result+=5;
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc5_4)&&(xb1<xc5_2))&&((yb1>yc5_4)&&(yb1<yc5_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc5_4)&&(xb2<xc5_2))&&((yb2>yc5_4)&&(yb2<yc5_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc5_4)&&(xb3<xc5_2))&&((yb3>yc5_4)&&(yb3<yc5_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc5_4)&&(xb4<xc5_2))&&((yb4>yc5_4)&&(yb4<yc5_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    chkc5=1;
                    coinSong.start();
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc6_4)&&(xb1<xc6_2))&&((yb1>yc6_4)&&(yb1<yc6_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc6_4)&&(xb2<xc6_2))&&((yb2>yc6_4)&&(yb2<yc6_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc6_4)&&(xb3<xc6_2))&&((yb3>yc6_4)&&(yb3<yc6_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc6_4)&&(xb4<xc6_2))&&((yb4>yc6_4)&&(yb4<yc6_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    chkc6=1;
                    coinSong.start();
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc7_4)&&(xb1<xc7_2))&&((yb1>yc7_4)&&(yb1<yc7_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc7_4)&&(xb2<xc7_2))&&((yb2>yc7_4)&&(yb2<yc7_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc7_4)&&(xb3<xc7_2))&&((yb3>yc7_4)&&(yb3<yc7_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc7_4)&&(xb4<xc7_2))&&((yb4>yc7_4)&&(yb4<yc7_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    chkc7=1;
                    coinSong.start();
                }


                if(     ((xb1>xc8_4)&&(xb1<xc8_2))&&((yb1>yc8_4)&&(yb1<yc8_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc8_4)&&(xb2<xc8_2))&&((yb2>yc8_4)&&(yb2<yc8_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc8_4)&&(xb3<xc8_2))&&((yb3>yc8_4)&&(yb3<yc8_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc8_4)&&(xb4<xc8_2))&&((yb4>yc8_4)&&(yb4<yc8_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    coinSong.start();
                    chkc8=1;
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc9_4)&&(xb1<xc9_2))&&((yb1>yc9_4)&&(yb1<yc9_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc9_4)&&(xb2<xc9_2))&&((yb2>yc9_4)&&(yb2<yc9_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc9_4)&&(xb3<xc9_2))&&((yb3>yc9_4)&&(yb3<yc9_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc9_4)&&(xb4<xc9_2))&&((yb4>yc9_4)&&(yb4<yc9_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    coinSong.start();
                    chkc9=1;
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc10_4)&&(xb1<xc10_2))&&((yb1>yc10_4)&&(yb1<yc10_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc10_4)&&(xb2<xc10_2))&&((yb2>yc10_4)&&(yb2<yc10_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc10_4)&&(xb3<xc10_2))&&((yb3>yc10_4)&&(yb3<yc10_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc10_4)&&(xb4<xc10_2))&&((yb4>yc10_4)&&(yb4<yc10_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    coinSong.start();
                    chkc10=1;
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc11_4)&&(xb1<xc11_2))&&((yb1>yc11_4)&&(yb1<yc11_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc11_4)&&(xb2<xc11_2))&&((yb2>yc11_4)&&(yb2<yc11_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc11_4)&&(xb3<xc11_2))&&((yb3>yc11_4)&&(yb3<yc11_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc11_4)&&(xb4<xc11_2))&&((yb4>yc11_4)&&(yb4<yc11_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    coinSong.start();
                    chkc11=1;
                }

                if(     ((xb1>xc12_4)&&(xb1<xc12_2))&&((yb1>yc12_4)&&(yb1<yc12_2))||
                        ((xb2>xc12_4)&&(xb2<xc12_2))&&((yb2>yc12_4)&&(yb2<yc12_2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xc12_4)&&(xb3<xc12_2))&&((yb3>yc12_4)&&(yb3<yc12_2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xc12_4)&&(xb4<xc12_2))&&((yb4>yc12_4)&&(yb4<yc12_2))      )
                {
                    result+=5;
                    coinSong.start();
                    chkc12=1;
                }

        // ball Coordinates
                xb1=ballX;
                xb2=ballX+ball.getWidth();
                xb3=ballX;
                xb4=ballX+ball.getWidth();
                yb1=ballY;
                yb2=ballY;
                yb3=ballY-ball.getHeight();
                yb4=ballY-ball.getWidth();

        //Eat Coordinates

                xe1=eatX;
                xe2=eatX+eat.getWidth();
                xe3=eatX+eat.getWidth();
                xe4=eatX;
                ye1=eatY;
                ye2=eatY;
                ye3=eatY-eat.getHeight();
                ye4=eatY-eat.getHeight();

                xe11=eatX2;
                xe22=eatX2+eat.getWidth();
                xe33=eatX2+eat.getWidth();
                xe44=eatX2;
                ye11=eatt;
                ye22=eatt;
                ye33=eatt-eat.getHeight();
                ye44=eatt-eat.getHeight();

    // Ball touching Eat

                if(     ((xb1>xe4)&&(xb1<xe2))&&((yb1>ye4)&&(yb1<ye2))||
                        ((xb2>xe4)&&(xb2<xe2))&&((yb2>ye4)&&(yb2<ye2)) ||
                        ((xb3>xe4)&&(xb3<xe2))&&((yb3>ye4)&&(yb3<ye2)) ||
                        ((xb4>xe4)&&(xb4<xe2))&&((yb4>ye4)&&(yb4<ye2))      )
                {
                    Intent menu = new Intent(Game.this,score.class);
                    menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(menu);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, ballX,ballY, null);

                if(     ((xb1>xe44)&&(xb1<xe22))&&((yb1>ye44)&&(yb1<ye22))||
                        ((xb2>xe44)&&(xb2<xe22))&&((yb2>ye44)&&(yb2<ye22)) ||
                        ((xb3>xe44)&&(xb3<xe22))&&((yb3>ye44)&&(yb3<ye22)) ||
                        ((xb4>xe44)&&(xb4<xe22))&&((yb4>ye44)&&(yb4<ye22))      )
                {
                    Intent menu = new Intent(Game.this,score.class);
                    menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(menu);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, ballX,ballY, null);



        // Finish Coordinate 

                fx1=0;
                fx2=5;
                fx3=0+finish.getWidth();
                fx4=0;
                fy1=350;
                fy2=350;
                fy3=350+finish.getHeight();
                fy4=400;

        // TOuching finish
                if(     ((xb1>fx4)&&(xb1<fx2))&&((yb1>fy4)&&(yb1<fy2))||
                        ((xb2>fx4)&&(xb2<fx2))&&((yb2>fy4)&&(yb2<fy2)) ||
                        ((xb3>fx4)&&(xb3<fx2))&&((yb3>fy4)&&(yb3<fy2)) ||
                        ((xb4>fx4)&&(xb4<fx2))&&((yb4>fy4)&&(yb4<fy2))      )
                {
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(Game.this,lvl_2.class);
                    nextScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, ballX,ballY, null);


                eatY=eatY+2;
                eatY2=eatY-2;
                eatX=eatX+1;
                eatX2=eatX2-1;

                if(eatY>canvas.getHeight()){ 
                    eatY=0;
                }
                if(eatX>canvas.getWidth()){
                    eatX=0;
                }
                if(eatX2<0){
                    eatX2=canvas.getWidth();
                }
                if(eatY2<0){
                    eatY2=canvas.getWidth();
                }

                my_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent menu = new Intent(Game.this,menu.class);
        menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(menu);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // full Screen 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Wake-lock
        PowerManager pM = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wL = pM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "whatever");
        wL.acquire();

        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size()!= 0){
            Sensor s= sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0) ;
            sm.registerListener(this , s,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        }
        finish=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.home);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
        //wallp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lvl1_bck);
        eat = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.rev);
        eat1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ur2l5);
        coin= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin1= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin2= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin3= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin4= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin5= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin6= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin7= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin8= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin9= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin10= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);
        coin11= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coins);

        x=y=sensorX=sensorY=0;
        eatX=0;
        eatY=5;
        //x=y=sensorX=sensorY=0;
        game_surface = new MySurface(this);
        game_surface.resume();
        setContentView(game_surface);
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            Intent it=new Intent(Game.this,lvl_2.class);
            startActivity(it);
            }
        };
        Timer t=new Timer();
        t.schedule(task, 5*1000);


        coinSong = MediaPlayer.create(Game.this,R.raw.coins);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(chk==1)
        {

            sencurrX=e.values[0];
            sencurrY=e.values[1];
            chk=2;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        sensorX = e.values[0]-sencurrX;
        sensorY = e.values[1]-sencurrY;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPause();
        coinSong.release();
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
        wL.release();
        finish();
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            if (resultCode == 1) {
                Intent i = getIntent();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                finish();

                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First, include a full logcat and stack trace so that the IllegalStateException can be properly examined.  Second, have you ever considered using arrays instead of all of those variables?

Answer (score 1):

I think your crash is caused by this code:

```
Intent menu = new Intent(Game.this,score.class);
                    menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(menu);
                    finish();
```

why did you put startActivity in a thread which is not main thread? You should use a handler to send message to main thread to start a new activity.

Comment: being a newbie as you can see that in my code I don't have much experience of writing these kinds of code , so could you please tell me specifically how can I "use a handler to send message to main thread to start a new activity."

Comment: 07-31 16:35:51.318: E/AndroidRuntime(18380): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13

07-31 16:35:51.318: E/AndroidRuntime(18380): java.lang.IllegalStateException

07-31 16:35:51.318: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):  at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)

07-31 16:35:51.318: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:819)

07-31 16:35:51.318: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):  at com.example.ballmania.Game$MySurface.run(Game.java:354)
07-31 16:35:51.318: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Comment: Check the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) reference. or you can search the sample code in API demo which is located at your SDK package.